# One-to-one of its domain and inverse is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis

> For the function $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by$$
> \varphi(q) = 
> \begin{cases}
> -q & \text{if $q\leq 0$}\\
> q\sqrt{2} & \text{if $q\geq 0$}\\
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   1)Prove $\varphi$ is one-to-one on its domain.
>
> 2)Prove that the inverse of $\varphi$ is not continuous.

1) A one-to-one function has at most one element in the domain mapped to a particular element in the co-domain. Such that $\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)\Rightarrow-a=-b\Rightarrow a=b$ and $\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)\Rightarrow a\sqrt{2}=b\sqrt{2}\Rightarrow a=b$.

2) Show that the image of $(−\infty,0)$ is not open. Since $q\geq0$ and then provided that given any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a real number $N<0$ such that $q<N$ implies $\varphi(q)<\alpha$, then $\lim_{q\rightarrow-\infty}\varphi(q)=-\infty$. Therefore, the image is not open.

Answer (score 0):

1. We know that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.
   Suppose $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$ and $x < y$.
   Since $\phi$ is decreasing for $x \le 0$ and increasing for $0\le x$, we have $x < 0 < y$.
   Hence $\sqrt 2 = x / y$.
   So $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

This is a contradiction.

2. $\sqrt 2$ is irrational but can be approximated by $x$ as near as we want. $\phi(-x) \leadsto \phi(1)$ when $x\leadsto \sqrt 2$.
   This proves that the inverse is discontinuous in 1. The same argument applies everywhere.